# Formula calculated from multiple fields

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a formula that's dynamically generated based on other fields. This is for the Opportunity object.

I want 'warnings' text field to check multiple fields ('a','b','c','d','e',etc) if they are '0' in a dropdown. If they are '0' or blank, I need to put that value in a field.

For example:

If 'a' and 'e' are empty, then the 'warnings' field show say 'A, E'.

If 'a', 'd', and 'f' are empty, then the 'warnings' field would say 'A, D, F'

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: What's is "a,b,c,d"? Are they individual fields or picklist values?

Comment: Individual fields, each is a picklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like below in the formula editor , basically you want to check each picklist value and then concatenate each blanks/null to text.

```
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( A_fld )), "A,", "" ) &
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( B_fld )), "B,", "" ) &
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( C_fld )), "C,", "" ) &
…..................
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( X_fld )), "X",  "" )
```

---

Demo in my dev org

Formula field : TestPicklistValues

formula:

```
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( AccountSource )), "Source," , "") &
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( Active__c )), "Active,", "" ) &
IF( ISBLANK(TEXT( Rating )), "Rating", "" )
```

**System**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I pasted this with edits into the formula editor, and received 

"Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text"

Comment: It works for me perfectly.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you!

Comment: @Mark please mark the answer as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate *n* IFs

```
IF (OR (ISPICKVAL(A__c,''),ISPICKVAL(A__c,'0'),'A,',NULL) & 
IF (OR (ISPICKVAL(B__c,''),ISPICKVAL(B__c,'0'),'B,',NULL) & 
...
```

this will leave you with a trailing `,` if any warnings. If you care, you can deal with that by wrapping the formula with some additional logic to strip it out - an exercise left for the reader

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question - can you explain which of these values I should edit? What's the difference between '0' and 'A'?

Comment: `0` is the dropdown value per your requirements, `A--c` is custom field A, `B__c` is custom field B, ..